# Writing Interface with ALL optional parameters Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider this:

```
interface TArguments {
    width?: number,
    height?: number
}

interface TSomeFunction {
    someFunction ({width, height}: TArguments): void
}

const someObject: TSomeFunction = {
    someFunction ({width, height}) {
    // do something, no return
    }
}
```

Both paremeters are **optional**, this means that I can call someFunction like that:

```
 someObject.someFunction() // but it is not passing through
```

I'm geting an Error "Expected 1 arguments, but got 0".

Am I missing something ?
How do I write an Interface when all parameters are optional?

Comment: Note that what you've written for adding `{}` as a default is not the same as the answer. Also, your question is less about writing an interface and more about writing a function definition, which happens to be a method in an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interface should not concern about default values or destructuring, as those are implementation details. Just declare the parameter as optional, as if it was a scalar:

```
interface TSomeFunction {
    someFunction (size? : TArguments): void
}
```

The implementation can then define both:

```
const someObject: TSomeFunction = {
    someFunction({ width, height } = {}) {
    // do something, no return
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your error must be coming from a different place (or try restarting your IDE, that is a source of a lot of frustration :)). Your second approach looks correct:

```js
const someFunction = ({width, height}: TArguments = {}) => { ... }
```

Here is a working [TypeScript playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoEEoHMCuBbCcAZ2QG8AoZK5Ad2ABMwALAfgC5kR8AjaZAH044ANsIA0lakwjAsTMOyF5eUAUNHkAvuXIIA9iCJhkRPQQBiOEAjDADyALzIAFKVoNmY5NNnzkmjgxsfEIwEidSTQBKDgA3PQZHAD4ySWQAenTkej0TMwhmUCwvEFyoApwoEC0dUwsrGzsQZyiAbiA)

**EDIT** You need to also specify that the parameter itself, not only its keys, is optional:

```js
interface TSomeFunction {
    someFunction (arguments?: TArguments): void; // Notice the question mark after the parameter expression
}

// Now you can either add a default value to your function
const someObject: TSomeFunction = {
    someFunction ({width, height}: TArguments = {}) {}
}


// Or leave it optional without specifying a default value
const someObject: TSomeFunction = {
    someFunction ({width, height}?: TArguments) {} // Notice the question mark
}
```