# Typescript: Declare interface with all optional indices accessible by "indexing into"

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

I want to create an interface that has all the CSS properties as possible indices but it could have none, and I want to "index into" it.

This would be ideal but it is not working:

```
declare interface ICSSStyles {
  [name: string]: ICSSStyle;
  fontStyle?: ICSSStyle;
  alignContent?: ICSSStyle;
  color?: ICSSStyle;
}

declare interface ICSSStyle {
  value: any;
  weight: number;
}

let obj: ICSSStyles = {
  fontStyle: {value: "italic", weight: 1000}, 
  color: {value: "red", weight: 100}
}

for (let key in obj) {
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```

The error I get when I hover over alignContent is: "Property 'alignContent' of type 'ICSSStyle | undefined' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'ICSSStyle'."

All of the indices must be optional because it's possible that any will be present or none. I also need to get to them through a string index, like the for...in loop above.

I have found similar questions [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76756009/typescript-create-a-string-indexed-interface-with-optional-properties) and [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62761481/writing-interface-with-all-optional-parameters-typescript), but if they have given me the answer, I have missed it.

How can I set this up?

Comment: The answer to the second question you found seems to apply, it suggests `[name: string]: string | undefined;`

Comment: Oh man, @Bergi, I thought I had tried that and it didn't work. Apparently, I either did it wrong or never tried it because that totally works now! Thank you. I guess this was a "Talk with the Rubber Ducky about it" situation.

Comment: Except I set it up like this: `[name: string]: ICSSStyle | undefined;`